# Visual Studio Optimization Even When Optimization Disabled?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, optimization, c++11, constructor

I'm playing around with move and copy constructors just to learn a bit more about them, and ran into this little bit of oddness that has me scratching my head a bit. Basically, I've made a class with a constructor, destructor, copy constructor, and move constructor overridden and I'm constructing them in different ways in order to see how the constructors are called. I've found a call order though that doesn't produce the results I expect. Keep in mind I have optimization completely disabled here and I'm compiling in VS2012. Are inlines still at all possible in this case?

Here is the source code I've written.

```
class RvalueTest
{
public:
    RvalueTest() {
        printf("CONSTRUCTOR\n");
    }

    RvalueTest(const RvalueTest& r) {
        printf("COPY CONSTRUCTOR\n");
    }

    RvalueTest(RvalueTest&& r) {
        printf("MOVE CONSTRUCTOR\n");
    }
};

__declspec(noinline)
RvalueTest GetRvalueTest() {
    return RvalueTest();
}
```

I then test it using the following code.

```
RvalueTest t1;
RvalueTest t2(t1);
RvalueTest t3(GetRvalueTest());
```

What I expect to see is the following.

```
CONSTRUCTOR
COPY CONSTRUCTOR
CONSTRUCTOR
MOVE CONSTRUCTOR
```

What I actually see is this though.

```
CONSTRUCTOR
COPY CONSTRUCTOR
CONSTRUCTOR
```

It seems that the last line is being inlined into a single constructor call, which naturally should happen if optimization was enabled. Would this still happen even though I have optimization completely turned off? Stranger still, if I do the following.

```
RvalueTest t1;
RvalueTest t2(t1);
RvalueTest t3(RvalueTest(GetRvalueTest()));
```

I get the following result

```
CONSTRUCTOR
COPY CONSTRUCTOR
```

Comment: What flags are you passing to the compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first example it seems the compiler is indeed eliding the move constructor call. Compilers are allowed to do so, whether optimization is enabled or not, and whether the copy/move constructor being elided has side effects or not.

In the second case you've got a case of the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) going on.

```
RvalueTest t3(RvalueTest(GetRvalueTest()));
```

This defines `t3` as a function that takes a pointer to a function with the signature `RvalueTest(*)()` and returns an `RvalueTest` by value. Use braces to fix this (may not work with VS2012)

```
RvalueTest t3(RvalueTest{GetRvalueTest()});
//                      ^               ^
```

After making that change, I get the following output with VS2013:

```
CONSTRUCTOR
COPY CONSTRUCTOR
CONSTRUCTOR
MOVE CONSTRUCTOR
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much. I suspected as much. And thanks for the link to the most vexing parse. It truly lives up to its name.